# Determinant and norm of the cross product

Tags: linear-algebra

I assume the vectors are in Euclidean space.

I know that the determinant of a vector family is the area/volume of the associated parallelogram/parallelepiped. But I also read that the norm of the cross product was the same area. So do we have $\det(u,v)=\|u\wedge v\|$? How to prove it?

Is it only true for two vectors or do we have relationships such as $\det(u,v,v)=\|u\wedge v\wedge w\|$?

Comment: How do you define $u \wedge v $ in dimension greater than $3$?

Comment: I clarified the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $\det(u_1\cdots u_k)$ doesn't make sense unless $(u_1\cdots u_k)$ is a square matrix, i.e. $k=n$.

(I am treating vectors as column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

The inner product in $\Lambda^k\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies

$$ \langle u_1\wedge\cdots\wedge u_k,v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k\rangle=\det [u_i\cdot v_j] $$

That is, the $ij$ entry (of the matrix we take the determinant of) is the dot product of $u_i$ and $v_j$.

In particular the norm is given by the so-called Gramian determinant:

$$ \|u_1\wedge\cdots u_k\|^2=\det[u_i\cdot u_j] $$

If we write $U=(u_1\cdots u_k)$, not necessarily a square matrix, then this is $\det(U^TU)$.

When $U$ is a square matrix, this simplifies to $\|u_1\wedge\cdots\wedge u_k\|=\det U$, yes.